# When does the garbage collector free the 'request' object?

Tags: node.js, garbage-collection

```
var http = require('http');
function createRequest() {
    var options = {};
    var request = http.request(options, function(response) {});
    request.end();
}
createRequest();
```

Above is a small Node.js snippet. The return value of [`http.request`](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_request_options_callback) is an instance of [`http.ClientRequest`](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_class_http_clientrequest) and is stored in a local variable `request` inside the function `createRequest`.

The snippet is a part of a bigger application that does multiple calls to `createRequest`. I am confused as to when are these instances returned by the `http.request` call garbage collected in Node.js.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this particular case `request` will never be garbage-collected, since you haven't read any data from `response`, and response has a `response.req` reference to `request`.

However, in this case:

```
var http = require('http');
function createRequest() {
    var options = {};
    var request = http.request(options, function(response) {
        response.resume()
    });
    request.end();
}
createRequest();
```

`request` will be garbage-collected eventually after response emits `end` event.

Comment: "response has a `response.req` reference to `request`", can you point me to a link which documents this ?

Comment: I don't think this is documented, here is the code: https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/v0.10.22/lib/http.js#L1684. Anyway, garbage collector is not interested whether it is documented or not)

Comment: I think the request and response graph of objects will be detected as unreachable from the main program by the garbage collector and are thus eligible for garbage collection.